# How to compile a code-behind file with XAML from the command line?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, command-line

I have this XAML file (MainWindow.xaml):

```
<Window xmlns ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
 <Button>
   Click!
 </Button>
</Window>
```

I have this MainWindow.xaml.cs file (code-behind for the above xaml):

```
class MainWindow : Window{
}
```

I have this `.cs` file (Driver.cs) that launches the application:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

class EntryPoint{
[STAThread]
 public static void Main(){
  Application app = new Application();
  app.StartupUri = new Uri(@"path\to\MainWindow.xaml");
  app.Run();
 }
}
```

This is my command:

```
csc /target:exe /r:<dll list> Driver.cs
```

What i want to do is 'connect' my xaml and code-behind file from the command-line. I don't understand how to specify the value for `x:Class` in the xaml and compile the three files together. Right now, the above command works fine but without the code-behind. How do i plumb? I am trying to understand how to create a basic WPF app without the help of VS.

Comment: Are you committed to using the individual command line tools directly, or could you use msbuild?

Comment: I do not know msbuild. I just made a plan to use the compiler from the command line and compile the files without investigating much. Will it be easier with msbuild?

Comment: Yes, if you use msbuild you could create a project file which looks like the one Visual Studio uses (and you could use that as a starting point) then just run msbuild from the command line to build.

Comment: OK, thats fine. But any idea about the problem at hand?

Comment: I'd have to look at the normal build process in more detail. You're likely to have to run one tool to create some C# from the XAML (normally `Foo.g.cs`, IIRC) before running `csc`.

Comment: @JonSkeet did you ever figure something out about this? I'm trying to compile a WPF-application (with xaml-code) without using MSBuild, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: @Alxandr: Nope, I didn't look into it any further to be honest.